# res.download status ok but no file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, download

I've used multer to store a file on a seperate RESTful api. I have an angularjs project that I want to be able to download the stored file. I have tried just res.download with the file path that was provided with req.file.path. I've also tried with creating a var for fileName and doing res.download(filePath, fileName). I get status 200 but nothing downloads. I've even tried just creating an  link and setting the attribute download to the full path. Currently, it seems like something will download but then it is empty or won't open (not sure which). If anyone could either suggest what to fix in my code, give me a simpler option for downloading a file, or point me to a more detailed example of using angularjs and downloading a file I would appreciate it.

Server structure for pdf I'm trying to get

```
config
models
node_modules
public
routes
  -index.js <--This is where the route is for res.download()
uploads
  -file-1511841977913.pdf <--This is the file I want to reach
views
app.js
package.json
```

index.js (in routes folder)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var multer = require('multer');
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');
var User = mongoose.model('User');
var Resume = mongoose.model('Resume');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + file.mimetype.split('/')[1]);
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file')

router.post('/resumes/:resume_id', function(req, res, next){
  Resume.findById(req.params.resume_id, function(err, resume){
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    console.log(resume);
    var fileName = resume.file_path.split('/')[1];
    res.download(resume.file_path, fileName);
  })
})

module.exports = router;
```

resume.service.js (front_end service to call this route)

```
export default class Resume{
    constructor(AppConstants, $http, $state, $q){
        'ngInject';

        this._AppConstants = AppConstants;
        //User creates var _$http and assigns angular provided $http module
        this._$http = $http;
        //User creates var _$state and assigns angular provided $state module
        this._$state = $state;

        this._$q = $q;
    }
download(slug){
         console.log('entered service')
          this._$http({
              url: this._AppConstants.api + '/resumes/' + slug,
              method: "POST",
            //   data: {
            //     uri: uri
            //   },
              responseType: 'blob'
          }).then(
              (res) => {
                  console.log('Res', res);
                  var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
                  var blob = new Blob([res.data]);
                  var fileName = res.headers('content-disposition');
                  FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName);
              },
              (err) => {
                console.log('Unable to download the file')
              }
             )
        return;
     }
}
```

Controller

```
class DashboardCtrl {
  constructor(AppConstants, User, Post, Resume, $state, posts, resumes) {
    'ngInject';

    this._AppConstants = AppConstants;
    this._User = User;
    this._Post = Post;
    this._Resume = Resume;
    this._$state = $state;
    this.posts = posts;
    this.resumes = resumes;

    console.log(this.resumes);

    this.logout = User.logout.bind(User);

  }
downloadResume(slug){
    console.log('called download from controller');
    this._Resume.download(slug).then(
      () => {
        console.log('download successful');
      },
      (err) => {
        this.errors = err.data.errors;
      }  
    )
  }
}

export default DashboardCtrl;
```

HTML

```
<div class="resume-list">
  <h2 class='zaffre'><u>Resumes</u></h2>
  <div class="border border-primary rounded mb-2 OEDropShadow" ng-repeat="resume in $ctrl.resumes">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
           <h3 class='pl-1 pt-1' ng-bind="resume.name"></h3>
           <span><span class='pl-1 pt-1' ng-bind="resume.date | date:'MMM dd'"></span> <span class='pl-1 pt-1' ng-bind="resume.phone"></span> <span class='pl-1 pt-1' ng-bind="resume.email"></span></span>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="$ctrl.downloadResume(resume._id)"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
           <button type="button" class="close mr-1" aria-label="Close"  ng-click='$ctrl.deleteResume(resume._id)'>
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div><!--End of resume-list-->
```

Comment: What value do you see for `resume.file_path` in your logging? The second argument of `res.download` has nothing to do with finding the file on disk, it's the filename that gets sent to the client and it defaults to the filename at the end of the first argument. Have you tried using an absolute path?

Comment: uploads/file-1511841977913.pdf is the value for resume.file_path. I have tried what I thought was absolute path with __dirname + '/' + resume.file_path the log for that is /home/ubuntu/workspace/routes/uploads/file-1511841977913.pdf. I opened these empty download files in wordpad and it was serialized or something. I then renamed the file with a .pdf on the end and it was the pdf I wanted which makes me think that the download action is happening with the service not the res.download because the filename should be file-1511841977913.pdf if res.download was doing it.

Comment: These are client side warnings
"Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at DashboardCtrl.downloadResume" and
console.log(res) prints
{data: Blob(68732), status: 200, config: {…}, statusText: "OK", headers: ƒ}

Comment: I have solved the warning and understand more how the Blob is the download file I do want but right now it is looking to the headers for the naming and finds null so makes the name download. Is there a way in express to set my own header field and value before I send the response so that I can use that for the naming?